# How to estimate a proportion as a step function of time

Tags: count-data, methodology, point-estimation

There is a black-box mechanical process that, at any time, may be either succeeding or failing.  It is known that after an initial disturbance, the process will fail $X\%$ of the time for $N$ seconds, and thereafter it will fail $Y\%$ of the time; $X$ and $N$ are unknown but $Y \approx 0$.  The process is disturbed many times and whether it's succeeding or failing is checked at 1-second intervals until we observe ten successes in a row.  Typical data looks like this:

[image: Plot of proportion of failures as a function of time after a disturbance, with data at 1-second intervals in the range from 0 to 105 seconds elapsed. Each point has an error bar. For the first 90 seconds each point shows roughly 55% failures, then it drops to close to zero.]

The error bar on each point is a 99% binomial confidence interval (R's `binom.test`), with Bonferroni correction.

I want to estimate $X$ and $N$.  Given the above, I feel pretty confident eyeballing $N = 90$; for $X$, options I have experimented with include:

1. Run another `binom.test` aggregating all of the data in the $[0, 90)$ range.
2. Do a linear regression with a categorical predictor, $p \sim Y + (X-Y)\cdot1(t < 90)$
3. Various less-parametric versions of (2), e.g. robust regression and quantile regression.

For the above data, all of these give roughly the same answer of $X \approx 55\%$ and I don't know how to choose among them.  Significance testing is not useful in context, but I would like to be able to report a confidence interval for $X$.  Nonparametric methods are probably a good idea as there are many, poorly understood sources of noise.  What would you recommend?  (Bonus points for suggesting a principled way to estimate $N$ as well.)

[EDIT: A fourth possibility has occurred to me: combine all the observations into a 2x2 contingency table where one axis is time less than or greater than $N$, and the other is successes or failures.  Fisher's exact test could then be applied. The problem with this is I don't know if it's sound to combine observations by adding up the counts in each category, or if there's another way to do it.]